# Visual Studio Web Developer (C#) - GridView and FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

I have this homework in Visual Web Developer (ASP.NET - C#) and unfortunately I have not enough time to the deadline to study everything properly - I have to create GridView so it shows data in database. The problem I have is:

When I click on Edit button in a row I am supposed to go to "Edit mode of FormView" or to something that looks like that instead of "Edit mode of GridView" (so after clicking on Edit I am supposed to see only a form with 1 line for each column of gridview of the appropriate table record, not the same Gridview with just changed records of one line to TextBoxes...).

Consider Default.aspx like this please:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="id_people" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id_people" HeaderText="id_people" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="id_people" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="first_name" 
                    SortExpression="first_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="last_name" 
                    SortExpression="last_name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:InsertRowsWithGridViewConnectionString1 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [id_people], [first_name], [last_name] FROM [Table1]" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Table1] SET [first_name] = @first_name, [last_name] = @last_name WHERE [id_people] = @id_people">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="first_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="last_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="id_people" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you're on your own when it comes to doing your homework. Why don't you have a go at it and then ask specific questions if/when you get stuck.

Comment: That's what I have been doing for last 2 days...

Comment: Okay, so then where are you stuck? You haven't actually asked a question - you simply have described your assignment and posted the markup for your `default.aspx` page. That won't get you much help.

Comment: Besides this is just a rather small part of the homework.

Comment: Well the question is: "How can I solve the problem I described up?".

Comment: Right - so you're asking us to do your homework for you. Sorry, not going to happen. You must at least make an attempt at implementing the assignment, and then start asking questions when it doesn't build or you get runtime errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddPropertyDetails" runat="server" CssClass="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
        Width="400" EnableViewState="True">
        <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
            <span class="ui-dialog-title">
                Add Property Details</span>
            <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
            //ur content of dialog here
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

do not forget to add css file of jquery to leverage their classes

Comment: @Nikolas Jíša I guess the link I have given wud hlp u do ur assignments.As a quick tip u can use the CSS classes of jquery to style ur dialog boxes as professional.Here the code i created to hlp u. Happy coding